# Starting mongod with --nojournal option deletes existing journal files?

Tags: mongodb, journaling

My MongoDB had crashed due to **out of memory error** that occurred when it tried appending to a journal file. 
At that instance, my mongod.lock file was empty. I restarted mongod without any options. It was accepting connections normally. Then I ran mongo.exe, but was unable to connect to db. It got stuck to "connecting to test" but never connected successfully.

I ended that process and I restarted mongod with --nojournal option. But that didnt help either.

But now I see mongod.lock file non empty. Also,all my journal entries are deleted.

The question is, does --noJournal option deletes existing journal entries? Also, is there a way to recover the journal entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Recovering after a crash

First, please read this article:

[**Recover Data after an Unexpected Shutdown**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/recover-data-following-unexpected-shutdown/)

After a crash, you have two options:

- if it is a standalone instance, run `mongod` with the `--repair` option;
- if the instance is a part of a replica set, wipe all data and either restore from a backup or perform an initial sync from another replica set member.

## The --nojournal option

Running `mongod --nojournal` will **not** remove journal files. In fact, `mongod` will not even start if there are journal files present. It will give you the following message and shut down.

```
Error: journal files are present in journal directory, yet starting without journaling enabled.
It is recommended that you start with journaling enabled so that recovery may occur.
exception in initAndListen: 13597 can't start without --journal enabled when journal/ files are present, terminating
```

If you then run `mongod` without the `--nojournal` option, it will apply all changes saved in journal files and remove the files. Only then can you restart it with `--nojournal`.

I believe this is what happened in your case. You don't need to attempt to restore your journal files, as they are already applied to your data.

Comment: Dmytro Shevchenko, Your answer is very insightful. As per your answer, I just need to run mongod --repair because journal changes are already applied. But there is a small issue. My data size is around 50GB and the remaining free space in drive is around 20GB. I read online that,  the repair option needs memory at-least as much as the existing data size plus additional 2 GB. Do you think, I should just run mongod --repair. Or I should extend my hard-drive capacity before trying the --repair option. PS, my MongoDB is running on Microsoft 2012 R2 server. Thanks!

Comment: @riteshkasat OK, in that case, you shouldn't run repair until you have enough disk space.